# add detailButton to MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to add a button to the annotation view and assign an action to it. I've kind of figure it out only my code has a small issue.

```
// so when I touch the pin , and the annotation view is displayed , I create a button and add it to the view

    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
    {

        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    }
    // when the button is pressed , go to another view 

    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
    {
        NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped");
        ArticleViewController *det = [[ArticleViewController alloc]init];
        det.leTitle = view.annotation.title;
        det.link = @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco";
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:det animated:YES];

    }
```

Now , the problem is that the first time I touch the annotation and the button is created , 
the

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

function doesn't work . Only after I deselect the annotation and touch it again it works properly . Could you help me impove my code ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Found it !**

I just had to add the button in a function that is called before the one I put it first in .

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
    if(annotation != mapViewHandler.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";
        pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapViewHandler dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
            pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;

        //instatiate a detail-disclosure button and set it to appear on right side of annotation
        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

    }

    return pinAnnotation;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer if your problem is solved.